# Android: Expand the inputType of EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'd like to allow possible inputs of 0-9, "," or "-" for EditText and couldn't find an answer.

I know using the "|" as an separator is possible:

```
android:inputType="number|text"
```

But how can I archive something like this (too bad it doesn't work):

```
android:inputType="number|,|-"
```

Does anyone know?

Regards,

cody

---

Addition to the comment below:

> private class MyKeylistener extends
>   NumberKeyListener {
>
> ```
>     public int getInputType() {
>       return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;
>     }
>     @Override
>     protected char[] getAcceptedChars() {
>       return new char[] {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',',','-'};
>     }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to provide an arbitrary filter like that.  You have to use the provided [filter types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType).

If you can't find a combination of those types that does what you want, you probably need to do the filtering yourself using a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) or [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) on the EditText.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. You put the idea in my mind to search for a KeyListener. Here's what I found, perhaps it's useful for someone:

Comment: Just a note (I think the end of your comment got lost, so not sure exactly what you were saying, but...)  The OnKeyListener interface will only notify you of text entered via a physical keyboard, not from the onscreen keyboard (ime).  To listen for text changes from both you need to use one of methods I mentioned.

Comment: Ok.. good your mention that - in the emulator I couldn't type other characters into the field. I didn't know how to post code in the comment, I posted it above. Best Regards, cody