# EditText with input type = number , how to show user ":"

Tags: android, android-edittext

So, I want user to write two numbers divided by this symbol ":" in EditText. I've added TextWatcher to this EditText, so I can see what user is typing.

Thus, that's what I have in my Watcher in afterTextChanged.

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
{
   String textToEdit = s.toString();
   if  (s.length()==2)
   {
      String h = s.toString();
      h = h+":";
      edit.setText(h);
      edit.setSelection(edit.getText().length()); 
   }

}
```

When user type more than 2 digits, I'm adding ":" to EditText.

And here I have problem.
Input type of this EditText is "number",
so, only numbers can be there and ":" is not a number.

Little example:
User typed 24. afterTextChanged get it and add set "24:".
24 was a number , "24:" is a string.

So, now I have "24:" and when I try to delete something from EditText I get fatal error.

Is there any other way to show ":" in my EditText? Or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it will work, but try `android:digit="1234567890:"`

Comment: check the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300490/set-edittext-digits-programatically

Comment: Are you trying to let only time? maybe using `android:inputType="time"` does the trick

Comment: Unfortunately, no , it's pace (app for runners) @Javier

Comment: Then you'd better implementing some sort of custom filters or watchers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961960/android-expand-the-inputtype-of-edittext

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting `android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,:"` in the xml of the EditText

*Edit:
this might be `android:digits="0123456789:"` actually :p